# Testing against hacking attempts

Tags: php, html, security, cracking

I want to make sure my site is protected against hacking attempts and I think the best way to test is to try and hack my site myself. What sort of things do hackers do to try and hack my site?

E.g.,

**Test** -
**they might put javascript in a input field e.g.,**

`<“open javascript tag">window.location = “www.somewhereelse.com”;<“end javascript tag”>`

**Protection -**
Use php htmlentities function before displaying data.

What other things can I test against to make sure my site is safe?

Comment: No publicly accessible website is 100% safe.  As long as it's online, it could be hacked one way or the other.

Comment: Your web site could be 101% secure, but what about a 0day (web/ftp) server exploit? you're done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will find an extensive list of attacks here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:Attack

Answer (score 1):

The best choice is to use a vulnerability scanner.
I can recommend Acunetix, on Windows, nikto2 - cross platform and free, nessus - i would say the leader.

Answer (score 0):

There are companies that specialise purely in "Penetration Testing" which use a variety of manual and automated techniques to test your application - it'd be a huge task to learn the techniques and do it yourself.

However, you could have a look at the biggies yourself: Cross-Site-Scripting (XSS), SQL Injection, Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) etc. A bit of a Google should get you all the information you need on those.

Answer (score 0):

Since I understand that you have no any attacking (aka... defending) knowledge, the best solution in your case is to use some automatic vulnerability scanners.

For Windows I can suggest [Nessus](http://www.tenable.com/products/nessus-vulnerability-scanner) is a very good solution and free, if you obtain a [Nessus Home activation code](https://www.tenable.com/products/nessus/nessus-plugins/obtain-an-activation-code) first.

Also, Acunetix is a very nice solution (maybe the best commercial out there) that has a [free edition](https://www.acunetix.com/free-network-security-scan/) too.

Last (but not least) a very good and reliable source you can find [here](http://sectools.org/tag/vuln-scanners/)!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on this [Hack This Site](https://www.hackthissite.org)

There is lot of challenges where you will learn what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way for you to go is to run a vulnerability scan against your website. There are numerous ways hackers can get into your website much of will be Social-Engineering, exploiting unpatched Software. so make sure to update your website as soon as possible each time there is a patch released.

I will recommend you ask a hacker who does not know your personally to try to hack your website.